# Google Maps API: Cómo identificar cuándo estuve en cierto punto geográfico

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, geolocalización

Buenos días a todos, estoy realizando un proyecto donde puedo saber la ubicación geográfica de un módem GPS (DCT Syrus). La gracia del proyecto es que pueda ver en tiempo real la posición del módem en una página web y poder visualizarlo a través de la API de Google Maps. Ahora bien, los datos que se están enviando del módem son almacenados en una base de datos, la cual nos permite acceder al histórico de posiciones del módem. Hemos logrado visualizar la ubicación en un rango de tiempo introducido por el usuario.

Ahora bien nuestro propósito es **saber en qué tiempo pudo haber estado el módem en determinada localización.**

¿Es posible?

Pueden acceder a la demo de nuestra página en http://swajteam.ddns.net/maps.php

Comment: las posiciones GPS incluyen la hora de la muestra. por lo tanto revisa bien que datos tienes cuando los recibes y almacena la hora también :)

Comment: Claro @rnd, pero para la experiencia de usuario, me gustaría usar la API de google maps para que la persona pueda introducir una locación en específica. Ocurre que la API de Google Maps guarda la Latitud y la Longitd en un objeto llamado LatLon. ¿Cómo puedo extraer ese dato para que entonces pueda hacer la consulta a la base de datos?

Comment: Por favor alejandro aclara bien lo que deseas saber. "saber en qué tiempo pudo haber estado el módem en determinada localización" no es nada claro. Explica bien, poniéndote en el lugar de alguien que no sabe nada, de lo que estas preguntando. Asi recibiras una respuesta que te sirva a ti y quiza a otros. saludos!

Comment: Hola @rnd . Se trata de una consulta. En mi página ya puedo hacer una consulta de la posición dentro de un rango de tiempo determinado. Puedes hacer clic en Localización y verás. Lo que trato de buscar es lo contrario, que el usuario otorgue un sitio y la página me arroje la fecha y hora donde se estuvo en dicho sitio. Obviamente dentro de un rango o margen de error.

Comment: Has probado las spatial extensions de my sql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mientras mas datos de muestreo de la posición, puedes tener más certeza de cuanto tiempo estuvo el usuario en cierto punto. Puedes establecer una variación de latitud y longitud en la cual determinas el usuario se ha movido, ya que el registro de la geolocalización generalmente tiene un rango de variación.

Por ejemplo, puedes tener estos registros, iniciando la lectura a las  2016-03-17 14:28:57 :

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:28:57
Latitud: 11.01808
Longitud: -74.85007
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01808,-74.85007

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:29:00
Latitud: 11.01807
Longitud:-74.85008
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01807,-74.85008

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:29:20
Latitud: 11.01809
Longitud: -74.85005
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01809,-74.85005

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:29:40
Latitud: 11.01810
Longitud: -74.85006
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01810,-74.85006

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:30:02
Latitud: 11.01820
Longitud: -74.85021
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01820,-74.85021

#### Si definimos una variación de la latitud o longitud de +,-  0.00010 para determinar que se movió el usuario, podemos decir que en este punto se movió:

```
Fecha: 2016-03-17 14:30:02
Latitud: 11.01820
Longitud: -74.85021
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=20&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11.01820,-74.85021

y para calcular el tiempo...

```
Inicia usuario estatico: 
2016-03-17 14:28:57
Registra movimiento:
2016-03-17 14:30:02
```

**Podriamos determinar que estuvo aproximadamente 1 minuto y 5 segundos. La exactitud como te comento depende de la cantidad de muestras.**

Comment: Hola Elenasys, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme. Creo que no me hice entender. Mi propósito es que, por ejemplo, pueda introducir latitud y longitud en vez de el tiempo. Y que como respuesta, me diga a qué horas y en qué fecha estuvo en esa zona. Una de mis inquietudes es, como puedo extraer el objeto LatLon de Google Maps, para que lo pueda leer desde mi base de datos, ya que en la base de datos estos valores están separados en dos columnas. Lo siento por no haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Es decir, me gustaría que el usuario pudiera introducir la latitud y longitud en Google Maps, y que de este modo pueda obtener estos valores para realizar la consulta a la base de datos de la página. Luego de que lo obtenga, pueda arrojar a qué horas estuvo la persona en dicha zona.

Comment: @AlejandroHarrisBonet en google maps? o en tu aplicación que usa google maps ?

Comment: @rnd en mi api de Google Maps.